# make array keys available defined in one function available to second function

Tags: php, arrays, function, global

Can't seem to make this work.

I want to make the array below available to a second function but it always comes up empty

The main code is this:

```
function GenerateSitemap($params = array()) {          

$array = extract(shortcode_atts(array(                         
'title' => 'Site map',                         
'id'    => 'sitemap',                         
'depth' => 2                         
), $params));                                  

global $array; 

}  


function secondfunction()

{
global $array; 

print $title;

// this function throws an error and can't access the $title key from the first function
}

GenerateSitemap()

secondfunction()
```

I'd like to use the **title**, **id** or **depth** KEYS inside a second function. They just come up empty and throw an error

Comment: how are you calling it?  Have you used `print_r($your_array);` to see the output and make sure that the array is being written to?

Comment: `print $title` should read `print $array['title']` - like you say in the comment... you are accessing the title "key" from array. (Calling a variable "array" is confusing.)

Comment: Aside... why aren't you calling `GenerateSitemap()` from inside your `secondfunction()` and avoiding the need for a global variable?

Comment: Your code has several problems.  Semicolons are not optional in PHP.  You must make a variable global before you set it's value.  What does the function shortcode_atts return?  The extraction does not make the $title variable global, only the $array variable.

Answer (score 1):

"The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined."

https://www.php.net/language.variables.scope.php

You need to define the variable (at least initially) outside the function:

```
   $array = array();

    function GenerateSitemap($params = array()) {          
       global $array; 
       $array = extract(shortcode_atts(array(                         
          'title' => 'Site map',                         
         'id'    => 'sitemap',                         
         'depth' => 2                         
      ), $params));                                  
   }  

   function SecondFunction() {          
       global $array; 
       ...
   }
```

Comment: and define it as global in the function BEFORE you do anything with it, otherwise you're just playing with a local copy which'll get replaced with the global version.

Comment: You don't _need_ to define the variable outside the function, declaring it as global inside the function is enough.

Comment: If you test that code it simply doesn't work. You'll be able to access the GenerateSitemap function but the SecondFunction() will throw an error when you access it Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, which is my problem in the first place.

Comment: @omar: The `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING` is not as a result of calling the above code. Another part of _your_ code is generating that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable as `global` before you use it inside the function, otherwise it will implicitly create a local variable.

```
function myFunc() {
    global $myVar;
    $myVar = 'Hello World';
}

myFunc();
print_r($myVar);    // 'Hello World'
```

You don't actually have to declare it initially in the globalscope, you will not get a notice/warning/error, although it is obviously good practice to do so. (Although if good practice is the goal then you probably shouldn't be using global variables to begin with.)